# Advice about installing Django

Tags: software-installation, python3, django, spyder

I have installed Ubuntu Desktop within VMware. Python 3 is working OK. I am starting to feel comfortable working with Spyder IDE. Very soon I would like to install Django.

Some Python novice must have tried this. The obvious routes appear to be:

- Create a new virtual machine guest OS and start again.
- Try to install Django on what I already have, hoping that the 
  two packages will work together.

Please advise which would be better.

Comment: Questions about programming should be asked on [so]

Comment: Many thanks to karel. The virtual envronment cant upset what already works. Python3 and its extensions go in there and fear is no longer the problemp

Comment: @CarlH I haven't seen any programming in this question yet, just software installation.

Comment: The title should be fixed, it looks like a bunch of keywords only. However, I failed to do this since I cannot understand the problem completely. @karel Could you fix the title?

Comment: @Melebius I fixed the question's title, as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the two alternatives in your question is better. Install Django in a Python virtual environment (*virtualenv*). You can install the latest versions of whatever additional Python packages you want in a Python virtual environment without degrading your operating system.

---

#### Install Python 3.x packages in a Python virtual environment

1. Install Python 3 virtual environment creator.

   ```
   sudo apt install virtualenv python3-virtualenv
   ```
2. Create a Python virtual environment for python3. You can only install python3 packages inside this Python virtual environment. If you also want to install Python 2.x packages, then you need to make another Python virtual environment.

   ```
   virtualenv -p python3 env # name the environment env or any other name 
   source ./env/bin/activate
   ```

   The new Python virtual environment for python3 will be created in the `env` directory which is located in the current directory.
3. Install Python packages.

   ```
   cd /path/to/env/ # env is the python3 virtual environment's directory
   source bin/activate
   python3 -m pip install first-package-name next-package-name last-package-name
   ```

This is a new python3 virtual environment with the latest version of pip3, so installing Python packages in it will work great.